# Card probability

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

There are two 10-card decks, consisting of 5 red cards and 5 blue cards each. Both are shuffled separately. One card is then dealt from each deck and compared. This is repeated for all 10 pairs of cards(one of each pair is taken from each deck). What's the chance that at least one pair consists of two cards of the same color?

---

I see that I'm supposed to use the complement as "at least" usually suggests that taking the complement is the easier approach. So I'm finding the prob that there are no pairs of the same color. This is where I'm stumped. I have Pr(A) = pair has no 2 reds, Pr(B) = pair has no 2 blues. For Pr(A) I calculated 20 choose 10 / 20 choose 10. But I know 20 choose 10 is wrong. Prob can't equal 1.

I'm wondering if I should calculate the prob of no red for each card in the pair and for each blue card as in P(A1) = not red, P(A2) = not red, P(B1) = not blue, P(B2) = not blue.

A push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: @5xum, what was the point of your edit?

Comment: A couple misspells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that each deck consists of $5$ *indistinguishable* reds and $5$ indistinguishable blues, and that we want the probability of at least one *colour* match.

Yes, we go for the probability of the complement, the probability of no colour match.

**Whatever** the arrangement of the reds and blues in the first deck is, we get no match precisely if the second deck has blues wherever the first has reds. Only **one** of the $\binom{10}{5}$ equally likely arrangements of red and blue in the second deck qualifies. So the probability of **no** colour match is $\dfrac{1}{\binom{10}{5}}$.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the answer. The calculation looks right as does the percentage. However, I'm trying to walk myself through it. What do you mean by only one of the 10 choose 5 equally likely arrangements qualify - which arrangement would that be?

Comment: @kitana97 : There are $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$ ways (each) to arrange the decks.  But for every arrangement of the first deck there will be only one arrangement of the second deck that will have the complemetary colours for all cards in order.  For example, if the first deck is $\color{blue}{B} \color{red}{R} \color{blue}{BB} \color{red}{RR} \color{blue}{BBB} \color{red}{R}$ then only if the second deck is $\color{red}{R} \color{blue}{B} \color{red}{RR} \color{blue}{BB} \color{red}{RRR} \color{blue}{B}$ will none of the cards match.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting this now. We are only looking at one deck for the total possible outcomes in the equation (10 choose 5) and there is only 1 arrangement where the desired outcome - not matches - that works which is when the second deck has the complement of the first in each pair. Correct?

Comment: Yes.  Only 1 of the 252 permutations of the second deck can be the complement of the first deck; whatever the arrangement of the first deck is. So $P(\text{Matches} \!=\! 0) = \frac 1 {252}$

Comment: Ahaha! ^^Explanation really pulled it together for me. Thank you :D

Comment: I would like to thank Graham Kemp for the additional colourful explanations. If we want, we could let the sample space have $\binom{10}{5}\times \binom{10}{5}$ elements, all ordered pairs of (first deck, second deck). Out of this sample space, exactly $\binom{10}{5}$ entries are favourable, namely the (first deck, second deck) such that second deck is the colour complement of first deck. In that analysis, the probability of no match is $\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}\binom{10}{5}}$, the same as in the answer above.